# Optimize combined rendering and canvas drawing in Android

Tags: android, optimization, canvas, rendering, hardware-acceleration

I have a set of highly optimized graphic routines for real-time effects (for a camera app)

The routine that uses them works in a layered mode in the following way:

```
Each time the process is executed (on each preview frame)

  > We have a bitmap (after YUV2RGB conversion) to start working with. Will call it B(0)
  > We have N independent sets of "layered lenses" with its properties: window (subset
   of the bitmap to be processed), color conversion, lighting, distortion, transparency...

For each lens (L=1...N), and sequentially, do the following:
  1) Take B(L-1) and, according to layer properties: process a subset of it.
  2) Draw the results onto the same bitmap. It will be called bitmap(L)
```

In 2) the drawing is made with a canvas, and it takes quite a long time if I need to scale it. I would like to speed-up this part.

I have heard of hardware-accelerated canvas and they are faster, but I am a little confused on its usage. I need something which draws faster but still gives me access to the results for further processing.

So, my question is:

- Do hardware-accelerated canvas only work with a view, or also with
  bitmaps? I.e., if I do, let's say N loops, but for each one I need
  the result of the previous, will it be of use?
- If not, any way to speed canvas drawing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Because we are not talking about overdraw and multiple view rendering on the screen, there's not so much to do with canvas drawing performance (yes, assuming the view is hardware accelerated).
Anyway, drawing bitmap data in a [SurfaceTexture](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.html) should be the faster way to "write" image data on the screen (as suggested by documentation).

Can you tell us more about the implementation? Looking at your composed task, I suppose that you can try to get more performance from the image-processing steps. How are they implemented? Usually fast image elaborations are made at native layer (JNI/C++) and using Renderscript where possible.
A good solution could be obtained moving all the elaboration at JNI level, processing the image as an Opengl ES texture which can be drawn very quickly inside a SurfaceTexture.

Comment: The image-processing steps are quite optimized using NEON.

Comment: Imagine you have different lenses on your image, and some of them can intersect, combining their effects. As they may include distortions and transparency, if next layer window intersects with the previous, I must use the previous results so it must be sequenced. Only if destination window (where it will be drawn)is the same as the source window, I can draw it directly in my processing step, but if the window is different, as my routines don't include scaling, I must compose it with a canvas. Sorry if a little bit confusing.

Comment: Got it. But are you using standard android bitmap? You can do this type of blending/multiply operations on a Opengl texture too.

Comment: Yes, they are sometimes arrays and sometimes android mutable bitmaps. I have never used OpenGL (don't even know how hard can the learning curve be), but it would definitely be the answer if I could take the results of the blending of each layer and use them as the source for the next layer rendering. When finished, give it again to the OpenGL texture so that it does the blending again and take again the results for next layer. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: Learning curve is the real problem, opengl is not trivial ;)  anyway all the things that you are able to do with a canvas are a subset of which you can do in opengl. My suggestion is to open a specific thread with specific questions regarding opengl on Android, merged with info from your scenario... And wait answer from some opengl Guru ;)